# Qual é mais correto, “plano de estudo” ou “plano de estudos”?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras

Em um plano de estudo a pessoa provavelmente irá estudar várias vezes, então seria melhor colocar a palavra “estudo” no plural?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O mais correto depende do que queres dizer. A meu ver, não é por um plano prever a repartição do estudo por várias sessões — segunda-feira da 9 às 11, terça-feira das 16 às 18, etc. — que se justifica o plural, ***estudos***. O plural justifica-se se o plano incluir várias disciplinas, especialmente se for um plano para um ano escolar ou para um ciclo de estudos completo, incluindo todas as disciplinas. ***Plano de estudos*** tem sido usado com este significado quer no Brasil quer em Portugal. Curiosamente, no Brasil tem sido usado no ensino secundário, enquanto em Portugal tem sido no superior.

Por exemplo no [site do Colégio do Padre Eustáquio, no Brasil](http://www.colegiopadreeustaquio.com.br/6-ao-9-ano/plano-de-estudos), temos:

> O Plano de Estudos é um instrumento pedagógico que apresenta os conteúdos e orientações sobre o desenvolvimento do trabalho a ser realizado em cada disciplina.

Podem ver aqui o [Plano de Estudos para 2ª etapa do 6º ano do colégio](http://www.colegiopadreeustaquio.com.br/images/imagens/6_ao_9_ano/Plano-de-estudos/2%C2%AAETAPA/plano_de_estudos_-_2%C2%AA_etapa_-_6%C2%BA_ano.pdf). E temos [aqui o Plano de Estudos ENEM 2016 do *mundo edu*](http://www.mundoedu.com.br/geografia), com informação pormenorizadas sobre os tópicos de todas as disciplinas de todos os anos; e podem ver [aqui plano de estudos da Faculdade de Direito da Universidade de Lisboa](http://www.fd.ulisboa.pt/cursos/licenciatura/plano-de-estudos/), com as disciplinas do curso completo.

Nestes casos, *estudos* refere-se às matérias a serem estudadas. Agora, usa-se no Brasil a expressão *planos de estudos* também para designar um plano muito mais pormenorizado, que pode chegar ao ponto de especificar horários semanais e os tempos a dedicar ao estudo de cada tópico. Vejam [aqui um exemplo](http://estudareaprender.com/como-fazer-plano-de-estudos-perfeito/). Neste caso a interpretação de *estudos* pode incluir quer as matérias a ser estudadas quer o ato de estudar em si.

Quando o plano diz respeito a um ciclo de estudos completo com várias disciplinas, parece-me apropriado usar-se o plural também nestes casos. O singular, *plano de estudo*, na minha sensibilidade, dá a ideia que se está a falar só de uma disciplina:

> Fiz um plano de estudo para o teste da próxima semana: capítulo 1 na terça, capítulo 2 na quarta…

Ou então que se quer pôr o foco no ato de estudar, independentemente das matérias, caso em que poderíamos talvez dizer *horário de estudo* em vez de *plano de estudo*:

> Fiz um plano de estudo: tenho aulas à tarde, então as manhãs de segunda a sexta são para o estudo, e fico com as noites e fins de semana livres para outras atividades.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45018/discussion-between-jacinto-and-sergio-mucciaccia).

Answer (score 3):

Obviamente **"um plano de estudo"**, **"um plano de ação"** ou **"um plano de gestão"** demandam algum tempo para serem executados. E é perfeitamente possível que um mesmo executor complete todas as etapas, uma a cada dia. **Contudo isso não faz com que um "plano de estudo/ação/gestão" seja necessariamente chamado de um "plano de estudos/ações/gestões".  Ele continua sendo um "plano de estudo"**

Se tivermos mais de um plano, o plural de **"plano de estudo"** é **"planos de estudo"**.  Da mesma forma, o plural de "plano de ação" é "planos de ação".

> [**PLURAL DOS SUBSTANTIVOS COMPOSTOS**](http://concisoecoeso.blogspot.com.br/2010/11/plural-dos-substantivos-compostos-parte.html):
> Quando os compostos vêm unidos por uma preposição, só o primeiro elemento varia:
>
> - Pé de moleque – Pés de moleque
> - Camisa de força – Camisas de força
> - Cana-de-açúcar – Canas-de-açúcar
> - Cartão de crédito – cartões de crédito
> - Máquina de costura – máquinas de costura
> - Pano de prato – panos de prato
> - etc.

Comment: O que dirias da resposta do Jacinto?

Comment: *Plano de estudo* e *plano de estudos* estão ambos no singular  (é um plano em qualquer dos casos) e são ambos válidos. O plural de qualquer um deles é *planos de*..., mas não me parece que seja essa a pergunta.

Comment: @JorgeB.  A pergunta diz que "a pessoa provavelmente irá estudar várias vezes, então seria melhor colocar a palavra “estudo” no plural?"  Minha resposta mostra que o plural de plano de estudo não é plano de estudos, faltou certamente dizer que em todo plano de estudo a pessoa irá estudar várias vezes...  que o número de vêzes não muda o número desse substantivo composto.  Esqueci de dizer isso, e o Jacinto o fez muito bem.  Da mesma forma, "plano de ação" pode englobar uma ou várias ações em dias diferentes, mas o plano é um só.   Já  "plano de estudos"  não me parece ser o tema da pergunta.